# android customized dialog

Tags: android, dialog, customization

I'm using a customized dialog box in my app.  It works fine in most of the scenarios.

i used the class customizedDialog as follows.

```
 public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog {
//how much time your popup window should appear
public static int POPUP_DISMISS_DELAY = 0;
private DismissPopup mDismissPopup = new DismissPopup();
public static boolean showDialog  = false;

public CustomizeDialog(Context context, String msg,int POPUP_DISMISS_DELAY) {
    super(context);
    /** 'Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE' - Used to hide the title */
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    /** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
    setContentView(R.layout.popup);
    CustomizeDialog.POPUP_DISMISS_DELAY = POPUP_DISMISS_DELAY;
            mDismissPopup.start();
            TextView popUpmssg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.popupmessage);
            popUpmssg.setText(msg);
}



 class DismissPopup extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        SystemClock.sleep(CustomizeDialog.POPUP_DISMISS_DELAY);
        dismiss();
    }
 }
```

}

The problem happens when i have to display two messages at the same time. In this scenario the second message comes over the first one. How can i solve this issue? please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with 2 messages?

Comment: I mean, i have to display two different messages one after the other almost at the same time. In this situation the second message must come after the first one expires. So i have used timer to display the second one. It works in some situation but not always. What will be the reason?

Comment: then try to show one dialog with merge two msg

Comment: its not possible. I have to show both the messages separately.

Answer (score 1):

Just show first dialog box.
And once the user tap(touch) on OK Button show the second one.

Showing two dialogs at a time is massing with User Interface Guidelines concepts!

Comment: actually i need an autoclose dialog box.

Comment: Then use a timer instead to close the first dialog box.